# Can't see Magento 2 front nor admin page on excluded IP when in maintenance mode. Using Varnish

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, nginx, varnish, magento2.3.3

So as I said, I am trying to see my website while others see it in maintenance.
BTW I have Varnish configured.

What I did:

```
magento maintenance:enable --ip=<my-ip-address>
```

What hapened:

1. At first I was able to see only frontend from **excluded IP**, but admin was regular "Service temporary unavailable" page.
2. Than I red about **maintenance.flag** in `var` and how it is what causes maintenance mode. So I deleted it to deactivate maintenance and again created it with touch. After that frontend was also unavailable from my **excluded IP**.

System:

- nginx
- magento 2.3.3
- mariadb 10.*
- php 7.2
- Varnish [latest as of today]

I followed official magento 2 installation guide along with [this](https://linuxize.com/series/how-to-install-and-configure-magento-2-on-centos-7/) for setup of varnish and letsencrypt.

I gathered from other questions that it is problem with varnish and it can be fixed with forwarding headers, but not sure how to do this on Nginx server.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of varnish so make nginx aware that you are behind the varnish.

1. Add these 2 lines in your /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file

   `set_real_ip_from   127.0.0.1; #Put the Ip of your varnish/proxy here`
   `real_ip_header      X-Forwarded-For; #Put the Header that your varnish/proxy set`
2. Also add below rule (usually /etc/varnish/default.vcl), in the vcl_recv part

   `set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;`

Answer (score 0):

Magento2 does not take in consideration by default of the X-Forwarded-For headers (...).

You need to add to the file `app/etc/di.xml`:

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="alternativeHeaders" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="http_x_forwarded_for" xsi:type="string">HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```